# How do you find the phase of the DFT of a discrete signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, phase

My question is similar to [this one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20032/the-phase-information-of-the-dft) and [this one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/60401/phase-of-the-dft), but neither answers address my concern.

Suppose you have a signal x(n) = {-1,2,-3,2,-1} where we can assume x(0) = -3.  So this is an even signal.

How do you find the phase of the DFT of x(n)?

Comment: What you show is not an even signal, did you mean x(n) = {1,2,-3,2,1}?

Comment: This post should help you: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/ffts-of-a-complex-signal-separating-the-real-and-imaginary-parts/38545#38545

Comment: Sorry my mistake.  Now it's even

Comment: @DanBoschen - I am not sure I see which part of the post is relevant to this question.  So the answer to this question is $\pi$, but I'm not sure I see why.

Comment: Your signal is real and it is an even function. So  the DFT is real. What is the phase of a real signal?

Comment: If you are saying the phase is zero, then why is the answer in textbook $\pi$ ?

Comment: the phase of a real signal can be $0$ or $\pi$, right? Solve for the DFT and then look at the sign if they are all negative then the phase is $\pi$

Comment: @DanBoschen - I am following what you are saying. But is there some general formula for finding the phase of an arbitrary list of real numbers?

Comment: If the real number is positive the phase is $0$, if the real number is negative, the phase is $\pi$. It's that simple.

Comment: @DanBoschen - I can ask a new question if you want. But just curious if you know of an example of a discrete signal whose phase is not 0 or $\pi$ ?

Comment: Any complex or imaginary number, so j would be the simplest example. Also $5e^{j\pi/3}$ or 2 + j3 are other examples.

Comment: But if you are asking for an example of sequence that would have an DFT that is not real, then refer again to my other question that I linked - it has all the properties of the FT they are trying to make sure you know. (Sorry if I seem like I am being cagey--- we're not supposed to do your homework for you but happy to help where you are stuck)

Comment: No problem, this was very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint that will help you:

The DFT is cyclical in time and in frequency. For the sequence given by

$$x(n) = [-1,2,-3,2,-1]$$

With x(0) = -3 would be solved using the standard DFT equation that starts at n=0 using

$$x(n) = [-3, 2, -1,-1, 2]$$

From that you can solve for the DFT and then determine easily for each result what it's phase is.